# How to get DisplayName of foreign field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Sorry because it's not clear but I tried to make it simple by the previous example, my actual models looks like:

```
public class Contractor
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public decimal contractor_no { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string contractor_name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contractor Class ID")]
    public string contractor_class_code_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contractor Class Line")]
    public short contractor_class_code_line { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("contractor_class_code_id, contractor_class_code_line")]
    [Display(Name = "Contractor Class")]
    public virtual CodeList CodeList_class { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contractor Status ID")]
    public string contractor_status_code_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contractor Status Line")]
    public short contractor_status_code_line { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("contractor_status_code_id, contractor_status_code_line")]
    public virtual CodeList CodeList_status { get; set; }
}

public class CodeList
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string code_list_id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "List Line")]
    public short code_list_line { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "List Value")]
    public string code_value { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is:
In view, the name of fields "contractor_class_code_line" and "contractor_status_code_line" is always the same which is "List Value" or "List Line" not make any sense.

How can I use names from contractor model "in this case Contractor Class Line and Contractor Status Line" instead of names from codelise model?

Comment: Well, you have set the display name to "Country Class Name" yourself. If you want it to be somthing esle, use something else. It's not clear what you want to do. Why should the display name for country name be city class name, anyway?

Comment: By the way, this sentence doesn't make any sense: "`DisplayName` of City class for `country_name` field."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved

It was:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.contractor_class_code_line, "contractor_class_code_line", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

changed to:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contractor_class_code_line, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

I pass label text by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I use this which works pretty well:

```
[DisplayName("Country Class Name")]
```

You'll have to include this using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Comment: `DisplayName` is old. `Display(Name=` should be used instead.

Comment: Sorry because it's not clear but I tried to make it simple by the previous example, my actual models like: